# ASP.NET: Auto-increment version number

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When I publish a .NET application, it will (if enabled) auto-increment the version number, in the assembly.
Is there any way to mimic this behavior, in an ASP.NET site?

We have a test enviroment that we publish to, and a live enviroment, and it would be really helpful, if I could add a label somewhere, showing the version.

Comment: ASP.NET itself doesn't auto-increment any build numbers or anything. ASP.NET doesn't build any source code and apply build numbers - that would be **Visual Studio** (ASP.NET is a **runtime environment** for web applications...)

Comment: I don't really see how this is a duplicate. The other article has to do with, from what I can tell, a winform application, where I have no problem doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked on Asp.Net in a long time but I think if you have "Web Application" instead of "Web Site" that should do what you are looking for.

Comment: The web app does seem to have an assembly version, but how can I get the publish function, in Visual Studio, to auto-increment it?

Comment: Visual Studio does it for you automatically. You just need to setup your AssemblyInfo.cs appropriately. i.e. Something like this for example - [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")] *******Remove the AssemblyFileVersion entry

Answer (score 1):

Try this Visual Studio add-in:

http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/